# How to choose multi files and get path of it to handle - php - zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, path

I wanna choose multi files with zend_form and get full path of its to handle in my action.
But I can't choose multi files as I need, just one file I can choose, and when submitted I catch an error "File 'videos' exceeds the defined ini size". Checking the page with Firebug, I see:

```
    <input type="hidden" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2097152" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE">
```

1. how to choose multi file
   /2.how to get physical paths of  files?
   / this is my form

   ```
    $videos = new Zend_Form_Element_File('videos');
    $videos->setLabel('Videos:')
    ->addValidator('Count', false, array('min' => 1, 'max' => 10))
    ->addFilter('StringTrim')
    ->addValidator('NotEmpty')
    ->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_File_Size('200MB'))
    ->setAttrib('enctype','multipart/form-data')
    ;
   ```

I just wanna get only paths of files, don't want to upload file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HTML5 multiple attribute to select multiple files.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
        <input type="file" multiple />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can get the path using javascript....

Comment: Thanks! vote up ^^ , using javascript to get paths is good solution to ignore Validator check file size.

Comment: ioi ioi! but i can't get full path of files , just only get name file in one of these files  
this is my code  

    function getPath(id)
    {
 var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
 alert(value);
    }  

 and result is a name of file =.=

Comment: Why you need the full path of the client machine. What are you trying to achieve? May be can help you if you can post your objective...

Comment: i just wana write a small app to get infomation of my videos , ex: filename , filesize, duration, resolution.....  support function require full path of video, Ex: $getID3->analyze($path);

Answer (score 0):

The path your referring to is the path to which the file is uploaded on your server. So you need to first upload the files to a specific folder (i.e. upload) on your server. And then get the path of the file.

I.e.

```
$adapter = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
$adapter->setDestination(APPLICATION_PATH.'/temp/upload');

if($adapter->receive()){
    $fileInfo = $adapter->getFileInfo();
    $filePath = APPLICATION_PATH.'/temp/upload/'.$fileInfo['uploadedFile']['name']
}
```

Comment: oh! these files placed in my vps and not to relate with my hosting, this function can be use by client with their video if they want use to get infomation of all video they got. although, at this time,just only me want to use this function, i know, this special case

Comment: after a long hours searching on google. I realize that I've just touch a serious problem about security, but in fact ,  I'm not mean to do something badly